# ensureErrorObject in then() (bluebird promises)

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird, requestjs

I'm trying to develop a function with bluebird and request. In the module I have:

```
module.prototype.getUsers = function (opts)
 {
    return new Promise(function(reject, resolve){
        request
        .post({
            url: opts.uri,
            form: {request: opts.req}
        },
        function(err, res, body){
            if(err)
            {
                reject(err);
            }
            else
            {
                resolve(body);
            }
        });

    });
 };
```

And in the Implementation I have:

```
obj.getUsers()
.then(
    function(res){
        console.log(res);
    })
.catch(
    function(err){
        throw(err);
    });
```

But I get: 
Unhandled rejection Error:  "result of request"

```
at Object.ensureErrorObject (C:\Dev\projects\testApi\node_modules
\bluebird\js\main\util.js:261:20)
    at Promise._rejectCallback (C:\Dev\projects\testApi\node_modules\
bluebird\js\main\promise.js:465:22)
    at C:\Dev\projects\testApi\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.
js:482:17
    at Request._callback (C:\Dev\projects\testApi\ebix.js:53:6)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Dev\projects\testApi\node_modules\re
quest\request.js:198:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Dev\projects\testApi\node_modules\requ
est\request.js:1057:14)
    at Request.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Dev\projects\testApi\node_modu
les\request\request.js:1003:12)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:943:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

What I'm doing wrong? I'm totally new with promises and bluebird.

Comment: That `.catch(function(err){ throw(err); })` does essentially nothing. Just omit it.

Comment: Will do. Thanks @Bergi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up the arguments of the `Promise` callback:

```
function(reject, resolve) { ... }
```

It should be [the other way around](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#new-promisefunctionfunction-resolve-function-reject-resolver---promise):

```
function(resolve, reject) { ... {
```